# Django: Get all inline objects in Admin's save_model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I have two related (via foreignKey relation) models and created admin model for parent with inlines. In a certain use-case, I need to fetch all related models and use those to update 1 particular field for parent model. What is the efficient way to do it?

My Models:

```
class ParentModel(BaseModel):
    text = models.CharField() # This is generated from inline children's data
    ...

class ChildModel(BaseModel):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentModel, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    ...

class ChildModelInline(TabularInline):
    model = ChildModel

class ParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildModelInline]
    ...
```

What I want is something similar to this:

```
class ParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChildModelInline]
    ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        inline_objects = <get_all_inline_objects>
        obj.text = <generate_text(inline_objects)>

        super(ParentModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `save_model` method is executed before the related objects are saved. This is obvious, because  the related objects must reference the primary key of the model.

You are probably looking for the `save_related` method.

```py
class ParentModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        super(ParentModelAdmin, self).save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):
        # form.instance stores the saved object
        form.instance.text = ...
        form.instance.save()
```

Comment: Is there a way to access this from the save_model method?  I would like to revert changes to the parent model if the inline models have a specific value.

Comment: The `save_model` method is called first and separately. I think that doesn't exists an easy way to do that. See the django related source [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1820).